# How do I get jQuery toggleClass (this) to function with multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar that is revealed by moving from the left into the viewport after a button is clicked and then moves back outside the viewport on the second click. This is all contained in an outer div and new copies of this are dynamically created as a new post is added and they should all function in the same way independently of each other. Right now each button in every new post only controls the sidebar in the first post. How do I use the (this) function to target only the sidebar with it's own button for each individual post?

```js
( function( $ ) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sidebar-button').click(function(e) { 
   $('#page1Wrap').toggleClass('toggleActive');
   });
  });
} )( jQuery );
```

```css
.sidebar-button { /* Sidebar reveal button */
   position: absolute;
   top: 1.55em;
   right: 1.6em;
            display: block;
            height: 1.75em;
            padding: 0 .5em;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 9px;
            font-size: .9rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 1em;
   color: #000000;
   z-index: 999;
 }

    #page1Wrap {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 60em !important;
  left: -20em;
  margin: 0 0 1.25em 0 !important;
 }
 .toggleActive {
  left: 0em !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <button class="sidebar-button" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars rotate"></i></button>
    <div id="page1Wrap">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1 class="category">Interaction</h1>
            <h4>Post category</h4>
            <h5>Project</h5>
            <h5>Brief</h5>
            <h5>Distribution format</h5>
            <h5>Software/technology used</h5>
            <h5>Notes</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="cell-1" style="background: url()"></div>
        <div class="cell-2" style="background: url()"></div>
        <div class="cell-3" style="background: url()"></div>
    </div> <!-- end page3Wrap -->
</div> <!-- end post -->
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead of ID and then: `$(this).closest('.post').find('.page1Wrap').toggleClass('toggleActive');` which would be more maintenable than e.g: `$(this).next('.page1Wrap').toggleClass('toggleActive');` but both in your case would work. As a side note, you need to [DELEGATE](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) click event to handle dynamic element too

Comment: How are those new posts added? With JQuery or do you loop through them with PHP or something?

Comment: And all that's said, you don't really need js/jq to do that kind of behaviour, some CSS only solutions would work too but that's an other story...

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff, I changed the id to a class and used the jquery snippet you provided. Works like a charm! :)